How to disable wxGrid cell highlighting?
As the title says - how to disable wxGrid selected (by mouse) cell highlighting like on the attached image.
I've tried using the SetCellHighlightColour method but it does NOTHING! There is still this blue marker on selected cells as on the screenshot.

what is your wx version? How did you create wxGrid? What option did you use for cell selection?

If you want to disallow selecting cells completely, you can call SetSelectionMode(wxGrid::wxGridSelectNone). If you want to customize its appearance you can use SetSelectionBackground() and SetSelectionForeground().
